# How to change plot background color?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a scatter plot in matplotlib and need to change the background of the actual plot to black.  I know how to change the face color of the plot using:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:mint green')
```

[image]

My issue is that this changes the color of the space around the plot. How to I change the actual background color of the plot?

Comment: Just FYI, in addition to what @Evert said, you could just use `ax.patch.set_facecolor('black')` (where `ax` is the axes instance).  `fig.patch` is the figure background and `ax.patch` is the axes background.

Comment: `mint green` is possibly the worst color you can choose for a background. I love it :D

Answer (score 375):

Use the **`set_facecolor(color)` method of the `axes` object**, which you've created one of the following ways:

- You created a figure and axis/es together

  ```
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
  ```
- You created a figure, then axis/es later

  ```
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1) # nrows, ncols, index
  ```
- You used the stateful API (if you're doing anything more than a few lines, and *especially* if you have multiple plots, the object-oriented methods above make life easier because you can refer to specific figures, plot on certain axes, and customize either)

  ```
  plt.plot(...)
  ax = plt.gca()
  ```

Then you can use `set_facecolor`:

```
ax.set_facecolor('xkcd:salmon')
ax.set_facecolor((1.0, 0.47, 0.42))
```

[image: example plot with pink background on the axes]

As a refresher for what colors can be:

> ### [matplotlib.colors](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html?highlight=color#module-matplotlib.colors)
>
> Matplotlib recognizes the following formats to specify a color:
>
> - an RGB or RGBA tuple of float values in `[0, 1]` (e.g., `(0.1, 0.2, 0.5)` or `(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3)`);
> - a hex RGB or RGBA string (e.g., `'#0F0F0F'` or `'#0F0F0F0F'`);
> - a string representation of a float value in `[0, 1]` inclusive for gray level (e.g., `'0.5'`);
> - one of `{'b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'w'}`;
> - a X11/CSS4 color name;
> - a name from the [xkcd color survey](https://xkcd.com/color/rgb/); prefixed with `'xkcd:'` (e.g., `'xkcd:sky blue'`);
> - one of `{'tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green', 'tab:red', 'tab:purple', 'tab:brown', 'tab:pink', 'tab:gray', 'tab:olive', 'tab:cyan'}` which are the Tableau Colors from the ‘T10’ categorical palette (which is the default color cycle);
> - a “CN” color spec, i.e. 'C' followed by a single digit, which is an index into the default property cycle (`matplotlib.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']`); the indexing occurs at artist creation time and defaults to black if the cycle does not include color.
>
> All string specifications of color, other than “CN”, are case-insensitive.

Comment: If there's some other common way to generate axes, let me know.

Comment: Looks like this method disappeared at some point over the last 3 years...  `MethodNotFound`

Comment: @Demis this method was added in recent years. See [ImportanceOfBeingEarnest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43391123/194586) for how to do it in older versions.

Answer (score 109):

One method is to manually set the default for the axis background color within your script (see [Customizing matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'black'
```

This is in contrast to Nick T's method which changes the background color for a specific `axes` object. Resetting the defaults is useful if you're making multiple different plots with similar styles and don't want to keep changing different `axes` objects.

*Note: The equivalent for*

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('black')
```

*from your question is:*

```
plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'black'
```

Comment: This is helpful! fyi I've just asked [Properly reset matplotlib.rcParams dictionary to its original defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59474405/3904031)

Answer (score 44):

Something like this? Use the `axisbg` keyword to `subplot`:

```
>>> from matplotlib.figure import Figure
>>> from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
>>> figure = Figure()
>>> canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
>>> axes = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='red')
>>> axes.plot([1,2,3])
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x2827e50>]
>>> canvas.print_figure('red-bg.png')
```

(Granted, not a scatter plot, and not a black background.)

[image]

Comment: I had success with `plt.subplot('111', axisbg='black')` before the plotting commands, using Windows.

Comment: The `axis_bg` `axis_bgcolor` were deprecated in matplotlib 2.0.0 and removed in matplotlib 2.2.0

Answer (score 34):

Simpler answer:

```
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_facecolor('silver')
```

Answer (score 21):

If you already have `axes` object, just like in [*Nick T*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23645437/2781698), you can also use

```
 ax.patch.set_facecolor('black')
```

Answer (score 21):

The easiest thing is probably to provide the color when you create the plot :

```
fig1 = plt.figure(facecolor=(1, 1, 1))
```

or

```
fig1, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, facecolor=(1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: This only changes the window background colour, not the actual plot colour

Answer (score 18):

One suggestion in other answers is to use `ax.set_axis_bgcolor("red")`. This however is deprecated, and doesn't work on MatPlotLib >= v2.0.

There is also the suggestion to use `ax.patch.set_facecolor("red")` (works on both MatPlotLib v1.5 & v2.2). While this works fine, an even easier solution for v2.0+ is to use

#### `ax.set_facecolor("red")`

Comment: FYI, `ax.set_axis_bgcolor("black")` works on Python v2.7.14/MPL v1.5.1, but `ax.set_facecolor()` does not.  Somewhere between MPL v1.5.1 and v2.2.0 the proper function got switched.

Comment: @Demis If you need to a solution which works in all versions, use `ax.patch.set_facecolor("red")`. Nut from matplotlib 2.0 on the recommended way is `ax.set_facecolor`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of NickT, you can also delete the background frame by setting it to "none" as explain here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67126649/8669161

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'none'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be useful for some people:

If you want to change the color of the background that **surrounds** the figure, you can use this:

```
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
```

So instead of this:

[image: Image with transparent background]

you get this:

[image]

Obviously you can set any color you'd want.

P.S. In case you accidentally don't see any difference between the two plots, try looking at StackOverflow using darkmode.

Comment: Which cmap is this that you are using. Or can you provide pseudo code for this chart with colours etc mentioned? It looks really nice.

Comment: Hi, I like seaborn's color schemes, so I just import their color ranks and use them in matplotlib as well.
For this particular plot I used the three following colours, defined in RGB format:
(255, 127, 0)
(166, 207, 227)
(176, 89, 40).
You can use this link to see how RGB colours will be mixed: https://www.csfieldguide.org.nz/en/interactives/rgb-mixer/