# Can't set the background on my matplotlib pie chart

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a server-generated pie chart in django using matplotlib.  My example view method looks like this:

```
def test_plot(response):
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure

    num_signed_off = random.randint(0, 10)
    num_reviewed = random.randint(0, 50)
    num_unreviewed = random.randint(0, 50)

    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
    ax.pie([num_signed_off, num_reviewed, num_unreviewed],
            labels=['Signed Off', 'Reviewed', 'Unreviewed'],
            colors=['b', 'r', 'g'],
            )
    ax.set_title('My Overall Stats')
    canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
    response=HttpResponse(content_type="image/png")
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

Everything comes out great, except the background of the pie chart is an ugly muddy grey.  I want it to match the rest of the page that it's embedded on, either by being transparent or by having a white background.  I can't find any option in ax.pie that will set the background color or transparency, and attempts to set the "axis_bg_color" in either `fig.add_subplot` or `ax.set_axis_bgcolor` have not had any effect on the output.  Is there some way I can fix this background color?

Answer (score 4):

Just add a `facecolor` parameter to the Figure:

```
fig = Figure(facecolor='white')
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089043/113962) suggests you need to set `axis_bg`, not `axis_bg_color` as you have in your question.