# How to set the default background color matplotlib plots for jupyter notebooks?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088687/how-to-change-plot-background-color) it was mentioned how to set the background color of a plot to mint green using:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('xkcd:mint green')
```

[image]

I wonder how to do set that as default. I can use the following command to set the color for all figures in a particular notebook:

```
plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'white'
```

When I run this inside a jupyter notebook it works. All images have no transparent, but white background. Though, when I add this to my matplotlibrc file nothing happens:

```
figure.facecolor : green
patch.facecolor : blue
```

I am sure the rc file is loaded. When I start the notebook, I use the following commands to produce a figure:

```
%pylab inline
plot(range(10))
```

What am I missing? Why has the parameter in the rc file no effect?