# How to change background of histogram plot and the sounding area?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using matplotlib.pyplot to plot a histogram and can not figure out how to change the background of the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y,x,mean=plt.hist(dataset.Y_Pos_Pivot,25,edgecolor = 'black', fill=True,facecolor='Blue',cumulative=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram]

Comment: You must use **Code** script to insert code. Use **```** before and after you type the code.

Comment: maybe you're looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088687/how-to-change-plot-background-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example for green background use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y,x,mean=plt.hist(nlvng[0],25,edgecolor = 'black', fill=True,facecolor='Blue',cumulative=False)
ax.set_facecolor("g")
plt.show()
```

Setting of axis `ax` property is needed.

Comment: How can you change the color of the outside of the graph? Thank you for your help

Comment: Outside graph, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088687/how-to-change-plot-background-color

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this: [How to change plot background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088687/how-to-change-plot-background-color)

In matplotlib, you can use "set_facecolor" in a subplot before you populate it with the histogram.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1) #Creates one figure with one subplot in one column
ax.set_facecolor('gray') #Set the background color to blue
ax = plt.hist(<Your data>) #Sets the subplot to be the histogram you want
```