# How to se BG color over an Histogram graph in matplotlb

Tags: matplotlib

How to se BG color over an Histogram graph in matplotlb
Need to add a background color to this graph [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3yZA.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = df['WASHING']
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x)


plt.setp(patches[0], 'facecolor', 'g')
plt.setp(patches[5], 'facecolor', 'blue')
plt.setp(patches[9], 'facecolor', 'yellow')


plt.title('CRUST')



plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.gca().set_facecolor('tomato')` see [How to change plot background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088687/how-to-change-plot-background-color)

Comment: It  was perfect, thanks a lot!