# how do I change the background of a plot made with streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I have the following code that produces a plot with Streamlit.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
plt.pie(label)
st.sidebar.pyplot(fig)
```

I want to change the default background color of the plot which is white in my case.
How can I do this? 
Let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the color py `matplotlib` config in the pie chart, because `streamlit` only display the chart into the UI.

To change the background color, you can follow `matplotlib.colors` build in function in [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/colors_api.html) and the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23645437/14699660)