# Is there a way to replace some cmap colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, colormap

I want to change the color yellow to goldenrod in the matplotlib cmap `RdYlBu`. Currently, the yellow in the center of `RdYlBu` is too bright and hard to see. I have tried various methods but have not found a way to solve this problem.

Doesn't anyone else find the `RdYlBu` cmap too bright in the center?

Here are some of the answers I found with bing AI.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# Get the RdYlBu colormap
rdylbu = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')

# Get the colors from the colormap
colors = rdylbu(np.linspace(0, 1, rdylbu.N))

# Define the range of colors to change (for example, all shades of yellow)
color_range = range(rdylbu.N//2 - 10, rdylbu.N//2 + 10)

# Create a gradient from yellow to goldenrod
yellow = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1])
goldenrod = np.array(plt.cm.get_cmap('Set2')(5))

for i in color_range:
    t = (i - color_range.start) / len(color_range)  # Normalized value in [0, 1]
    colors[i] = yellow * (1 - t) + goldenrod * t  # Linear interpolation

# Create a new colormap from the modified colors
new_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("RdYlBu_mod", colors)

xs = list(range(25))
ys = list(range(25))

sc = plt.scatter(xs, ys, c=ys, s=10, cmap=new_cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar(sc)

# Use the new colormap
# plt.imshow(, cmap=new_cmap)
plt.show()
```

[plt_plot_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZB8G.png)

However, this is not a complete solution, as it only replaces the middle part of the colormap with a new color. The newly inserted color of goldenrod does not connect with the existing cmap in a smooth gradient.

**The important part is that my data is float so my changed color map should maintain a smooth gradient. Other answers assume a clearly discrete cmap, which is not the case for my problem ( please see the figure).**

Comment: what about choosing another colormap from the existing ones? if you want to transition from blue to red without the fading white you can use the one called `jet`  or `turbo` . Check here the available ones and choose one that fits your needs   https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki the color itself has meaning. I want to visualize that my data has binary attribute, so It need only three color, red and blue on each side. We have considered other diverging colormap, but `coolwarm` is not vivid enough and the others has same problem(the center color is not visible on white background figure)

Comment: If it's not visible against white background have you considered changing the background color? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088687/how-to-change-plot-background-color

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki The figure is intended for a scientific paper. The background color of the scatter plot should be white…