# How can I setup the Matplotlib chart background to chromatic green and the line to chromatic red?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

How can I setup the Matplotlib chart background to chromatic green and the line to chromatic red?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp 
from scipy import stats 
import numpy.random as rnd
import scipy.stats as sts
M = 365
dt=1/M
r = 0.2
sigma = 0.15
sdt =sigma*np.sqrt(dt)
S0 = 100

def N011(VA1, VA2) : 
    N01=np.sqrt(-2.*np.log(1-VA1))*np.cos(2*np.pi*VA2) 
    return N01

SLIST = []
SLIST.append(S0)
for i in range(0,M-1):
    VA11 = rnd.random()
    VA22 = rnd.random()
    while ((VA11 == 0.) | (VA11 == 1.)):
        VA11 = rnd.random()
    while ((VA22 == 0.) | (VA22 == 1.)):
        VA22 = rnd.random()
    N01 =N011(VA11, VA22)
    SLIST.append(SLIST[i]*(1.+N01*sdt+r*dt))

tlist = np.linspace(0,365, num = 365)    

plt.figure(num=0,dpi = 120)
plt.plot(tlist, SLIST)
plt.show()
```

[image: FinancialStockSimulation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the background and line color by adjusting your plot generation code as follows:

```py
plt.figure(num=0,dpi = 120)
plt.plot(tlist, SLIST, color=(1, 0, 0))  # `color` is the line color
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor((0, 1, 0))  # to set the background
plt.show()
```

The arguments are the `(red, green, blue)` components of the color you want. You can choose from other ways of [specifying colors](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html), if you wish.

I found the answer to the background color question in [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088687/how-to-change-plot-background-color), and information about changing the line color is available in the [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html). (You could also set the line color by retrieving the appropriate line artist from `ax` and using its `set_color` method, e.g. `ax.get_children()[0].set_color((1, 0, 0))`, but that is more complicated.)

Comment: plt.title("Simulation du cours d'un actif financier")

Comment: The fact of adding the title to the plot alterates the axis intervals how to to fix that?

Comment: Also I guess chromatic metalic green is not RGB but a dynamic mix of RGB do you know of any documentation about that? :-)

Comment: I can suggest how to fix the axis intervals later, but I don't know what you mean by "chromatic metallic". Can you post a link to an example?

Comment: As-is, the axis limits will change whenever you write the function because the data is random and no seed is set. You can set the axis limits to whatever you want like `ax.set_xlim(0, 365); 
ax.set_ylim(np.min(SLIST), np.max(SLIST))`. You can further adjust the ticks with `set_xticks`, `set_yticks`, etc. Please see `matplotlib.axes` documentation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp 
from scipy import stats 
import numpy.random as rnd
import scipy.stats as sts
M = 365
dt=1/M
r = 0.2
sigma = 0.15
sdt =sigma*np.sqrt(dt)
S0 = 100

def N011(VA1, VA2) : 
    N01=np.sqrt(-2.*np.log(1-VA1))*np.cos(2*np.pi*VA2) 
    return N01

SLIST = []
SLIST.append(S0)
for i in range(0,M-1):
    VA11 = rnd.random()
    VA22 = rnd.random()
    while ((VA11 == 0.) | (VA11 == 1.)):
        VA11 = rnd.random()
    while ((VA22 == 0.) | (VA22 == 1.)):
        VA22 = rnd.random()
    N01 =N011(VA11, VA22)
    SLIST.append(SLIST[i]*(1.+N01*sdt+r*dt))

tlist = np.linspace(0,365, num = 365)    
plt.figure(num=0,dpi = 120)
plt.plot(tlist, SLIST, color=(1, 0, 0))  # `color` is the line color
plt.title("Simulation du cours d'un actif financier")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor((0, 1, 1))  # to set the background
ax.get_children()[0].set_color((1, 0, 0))
plt.xlabel("t", fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel("St", fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

This does that:

[image: Simulation d'un actif financier]

A fix to make the colors chromatic green and red Bloomberg style as a full .py file that self compiles would be greatly appreciated.